# How to pass an object to a java method using a4j:commandbutton

Tags: jsf, richfaces, parameter-passing

I have a rich:modal panel (code below). I want to pass the `#{currentLeg}` to the method called in `action="#{legHandler.assignAndInitLoadPlanning}`. But when I debug, at the method `legHandler.assignAndInitLoadPlanning`,  `resolveVariable("currentLeg");` returns an object with all its attribute values equal to null. It's attributes should not be null.

Additionally, this rich:modal is called from an `a4j:commandLink onclick="showUnitDialog();` on the same jsp file. If I change this said onclick to `onclick="#{legHandler.assignAndInitLoadPlanning}"` the currentleg will be passed properly but i cannot do this because i need to have a popup (which is a `rich:modalpanel`) to display. And I am using JSF 1.

I've already tried keep alive and set variable but still not works. It seems that the `currentLeg` is not properly passed. Do you have any idea why?

```
<rich:modalPanel id="unitDialog" width="400" height="100">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="Please Select Unit for the Leg"></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{currentLeg.legId}"></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>

        <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="2" columnClasses="colStyle1, colStyle2">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="legHandler.unit">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="kg" itemLabel="kg" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="lb" itemLabel="lb" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>


        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid style="text-align: center" columns="3"
                columnClasses="col1, col2" width="100%">

      <a4j:commandButton  value="Apply" styleClass="big_btn" 
                               id="applyButton" immediate="true" 
                               action="#{legHandler.assignAndInitLoadPlanning}" 
                                oncomplete="{#{rich:component('unitDialog')}.hide();}"> 
                                </a4j:commandButton>                                


            <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="big_btn"
                immediate="true"
                id="closeUnitPopupDialog"
                onclick="#{rich:component('unitDialog')}.hide();"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

</rich:modalPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EL 2.2+ you can simply pass the value as parameter:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{legHandler.assignAndInitLoadPlanning(currentLeg)}" … />
```

Otherwise use `a4j:actionparam` and save the value to the bean

```
<a4j:commandButton …>
    <a4j:actionparam name="currentLeg" value="#{currentLeg}" assignTo="#{legHandler.currentLeg}" />
<a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: didn't work for me :( but when I changed the value to #{currentLeg.legId} it was properly passed. legId is just an int. currentLeg is an object. It seems that I can pass an int but not an object. what do you think?